Cauchy Criterion for filtered modules
Let $M$ be a filtered $A$-module. How to show that $M$ is complete if and only if each Cauchy sequence converges in $M$? $\hat M$ denotes the Hausdorff completion of $M$ which is defined as the equivalence classes of all Cauchy sequences in $M$ and a module is complete if the canonical homomorphism $M\to \hat M$ sending each element to its constant sequence is surjective. I've done it the following way but it seems too easy to be true. Is it correct? I have not specified a single part in the proof to check because it is all just the same trick in both sides.
Let $\phi\colon M\to \hat M$ denote the canonical homomorphism. Suppose that all Cauchy sequences in $M$ converge. Let $[(x_\nu)]\in \hat M$. Then $x_\nu\to x$ for some $x\in M$ and so for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ we have $x_\nu\in x+M_n$ eventually and thus $x_\nu-x\in M_n$ showing that $x_\nu-x\to0$ and $\phi(x)=[(x)]=[(x_\nu)]$.
Conversely suppose that $\phi$ is surjective. Let $[(x_\nu)]$ be a Cauchy sequence in $M$. Since $\phi$ is surjective there exists $x$ in $M$ such that $\phi(x)=[(x)]=[(x_\nu)]$. Then for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ we have $x_\nu-x\in M_n$ eventually and thus $x_\nu\in x+M_n$ eventually, showing that $x_\nu\to x$.

What part are you doubtful of? The statement looks obvious enough to me, so it seems reasonable that it has an easy proof. You have essentially shown that both statements are equivalent to "every Cauchy sequence is equivalent to a constant sequence."

@arkeet I wasn't doubtful of any part which is what irked me. I searched for so long to find a "Cauchy Criterion" for filtered modules and everything I came across was so complicated. Glad to know it works. Thank you!
